# Mismatching Webdomain/URL

Tags: html, xml, url, editing

Several years ago, I created web site using Adobe GoLive 6, which has been discontinued and I have no working backup of the program at this time. I would like to relaunch this site temporarily as is, which has been fully developed.

The problem I have is this: The Adobe GoLive 6 project file was created using the original domain, let's call it www.bigbadstsuff.com. However, the original domain I used is no longer available. I currently have a similar domain, let's call it www.newbigbadstuff.com.

I cannot open or transfer the GoLive version of the site into any web design program that I know of. The only thing I would like and need to do is change the project file's name of GoLive created version of www.bigbadstuff.com to www.newbigbadstuff.com so that when it is uploaded to my server, it will be recognized.

I am not well-versed in this, but what would I change? Would I use a text editor to edit a GoLive XML file, the GoLive website data file, or something else?

I hope this was clear. (Plus, before someone criticizes me for using an old GoLive version of the site (which again will be temporary) or something, a new version of the site is being built up to current standards, but for now, I simply need to get this version back online. Thanks).